# Building an array from a nested JSON string in swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nested

I am trying to create an array of the most recent report dates associate with each name from the JSON string below. The report dates will not all be the same as can be seen below, and this will be done for a much larger group. Ultimately, I'll need to create arrays for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th most recent report dates as well. But I hope any clarity you can provide on the first array will be helpful in creating the others.

Thank you in advance.

JSON String

```
[
{
  "name": "John",
  "records": [
     {
        "reportDate": "2018-07-20",
        "hours": 204,
        "billable": 32844
     },
     {
        "reportDate": "2018-03-25",
        "hours": 234,
        "billable": 37715
     }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Sam",
  "records": [
     {
        "reportDate": "2018-06-18",
        "hours": 187,
        "billable": 13883
     },
     {
        "reportDate": "2018-04-02",
        "hours": 176,
        "billable": 13467
     }
  ]
}
]
```

Struct

```
struct Employee : Decodable {

let name : String?
let records : [Record]

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case name = "name"
case records
}

struct Record : Decodable {

let reportDate : String?
let hours : Int?
let billable : Int?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case reportDate = "reportDate"
    case hours = "hours"
    case billable = "billable"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    reportDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .reportDate)
    hours = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .hours)
    billable = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .billable)
}
}
}
```

JSON Decoding fiction

```
func downloadJSON( completed:@escaping ()->()){

guard let qurl = URL("https://website.com") else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: qurl) { (data, response, error) in
if error == nil {
    do{
        self.employeeData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Employee].self, from: data!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async{ completed() }
    } catch { print("JSON Error") }
}
}.resume()
}
```

Comment: @greg42627 You can get all dates from current JSON using this `let dates = self.employeeData.reduce(into: [String]()) { $0 = $0 + $1.records.map{$0.reportDate ?? ""} }`. Getting the most , second, third reported dates can be done easily. Use indexing for optimal performance

Comment: Why don't you consider my advice in your previous question to make the struct members non-optional and delete the initializer and all `CodingKeys`?

Comment: Thanks Cosmos Man! it worked. @vadian, I did in the code I'm using, I just copied the original question over that I hadn't adjusted. Thanks again for your help